# $ab=ba$ in an Abelian group. How about $abc=cba$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$ab=ba$ in an Abelian group. How about $abc=cba\;?$

If this holds in an Abelian group, please prove this.

Comment: $abc=acb=cab=cba$

Comment: Then if abc=cba, (a, b and c are in a group) the gruop is Abelian?

Comment: Yes, Lovelydia. If $abc = cba$, the group must be abelian. Associativity alone allows only for regrouping: $abc = (ab)c = a(bc)$. To go from $abc$ to $cba$ requires two commutations.

Comment: Thanks, both of you guys:)

Answer (score 6):

For an abelian group, commutativity of elements holds. And for any group, by definition, associativity holds. We use both properties:

$$abc = a(bc) = a(cb) = (cb)a = cba$$

Comment: If your class covers permutations, you'll learn that transpositions (2-cycles) generate all permutations. Because of this once you can flip any 2 things, you can shuffle any $n$-things in any order. :)